# Inefficient regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am learning regular expressions and I came across this example as for how not to write them.

```
/([01]+)+b/
```

The reason mentioned is that it is very inefficient since it involves a lot of backtracking.
Can someone explain why and what would be its efficient version?

Comment: By all means use `[01]+b`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but what of you need a capture group? ;)

Comment: Nested quantified overlapping terms, or singular unique terms are the only cause of catastrophic backtracking. Java, by contrast, has a stack problem separate issue that causes an overflow when you use an alternation group that is quantified. The people that posted answers in that duplicate link couldn't recognize a bad pattern 9 out of 10 times. All those answers failed.